# jquery mobile json listview - all the list loaded at one time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a problem with json parsing listview
as all the list loaded at one time
so take many time as its big
so i hope to find a way that make it loaded as how a webpage loaded
one by one

here is the code i use

```
$.getJSON(url1, function(json) {
    $('#blogList li').remove();

    $.each(json.posts, function(i,dat) {

    output='<li data-icon="false">';
    output += '<a href="singlePost.html?id=' + dat.id + '">';
    output +='<div class="ui-li-aside">';
    output+='<h3 id="titleMain">' + dat.title + '&nbsp;(' + dat.comment_count + ')</h3>';
//  output+='<h4 id="authorMain">' + dat.author.name + '</h4>';
    //output+='<p class="ui-li-aside">';
    output += (dat.thumbnail) ?
      '<img id="img" src="' + dat.thumbnail + '" alt="' + dat.title + '" class="ui-li-icon-right" width="100px" height="100px"/>':
      '<img src="Untitled.png" alt="View Source Logo"  class="ui-li-icon-right" width="100px" height="100px"/>';
  //   output+='</p>';
    output +='</div>';
    output+='</a>';
    output+='</li>';

        $('#blogList').append(output);

    });
    $('#blogList').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **Lazy Loading** approach to load only the content needed during a listview scroll. This way optimizes the performance of a mobile application.

[jquery.mobile.lazyloader](https://github.com/dcarrith/jquery.mobile.lazyloader) is a jQuery Mobile Widget for lazy loading listviews with AJAX calls to a server-side resource. It is a way to optimize the performance of mobile applications that contain a list of 50 or more items.

In addition, I would recommend to use a template engine like [Underscore.JS](http://underscorejs.org/) template engine instead of creating html code using concatenations.

If you don't want to use a Lazy Loading approach and want to keep your current implementation then try to move the `$('#blogList').append(output);` outside the loop. Also try to replace `append` with `html`. I have modified your code as following. Could you try whether the below implementation improves the performance?

```
$.getJSON(url1, function (json) {
    var output = '';
    $.each(json.posts, function (i, dat) {
        output += [
                    '<li data-icon="false">',
                    '<a href="singlePost.html?id=', dat.id, '">',
                    '<div class="ui-li-aside">',
                    '<h3 id="titleMain">', dat.title, '&nbsp;(', dat.comment_count, ')</h3>',
                    (dat.thumbnail) ?
                        ['<img id="img" src="', dat.thumbnail, '" alt="', dat.title, '" class="ui-li-icon-right" width="100px" height="100px"/>'].join("") :
                        '<img src="Untitled.png" alt="View Source Logo"  class="ui-li-icon-right" width="100px" height="100px"/>',
                    '</div>',
                    '</a>',
                    '</li>'
                ].join("");
    });
    $('#blogList').empty().html(output).listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) when i try to put it ouut of the loop only one li shown not the all list view

Comment: @MohamedOsama You're welcome. Regarding the one li shown, use the code I've posted.

Comment: when i try this it show one li too ,, sorry i'm still a noob :)

Comment: Could you try the code I've posted as is and check whether it improves the performance?

Comment: thanks bro for your time,, the code works ,, but it seems this cant solve the problem i have ,, it loaded exactly in the same time by the same way the first code i use,, i think i will try lazyloader hope it solve it

Comment: @MohamedOsama How many items are supposed to appear in the listview?

Comment: 10 items ,, it takes 6 sec to loaded but they loaded together ,, i like to make it loaded like a webpage item by item

Comment: so the user didn't wait until the whole page loaded

Comment: @MohamedOsama Sorry I have misunderstood the case and maybe the lazy loader is not the solution to your case. Can you explain in detail what is the problem? Why it takes 6 seconds?

Comment: i'm making a webapp that get the data from a wordpress via json ,, the index page (all li items ) loaded in the same time,, it take (6 sec ) and my users have a poor internet connections so it may take more than that,, to solve this i wanna the listview appear item by item ( the first one after 1 sec the second after 2 sec ... ) -- u know like what an internet browser do ,, it load any normal page item by item ,, my english is not good i hope u know that i mean

Comment: 6 second according my mobile internet connection